# Multiple log4j xml files for multiple applications

Tags: java, logging, log4j, error-logging

I have 5 applications which have different log4j xml configuration file. And I want each of them to be configured according to the given file and logs correctly when called from one main method.

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749015/class-loggin-to-multiple-log-files-with-log4j

Comment: @Kaj Problem is: All logs are going in the log file configured in the project using main method.

Comment: What are you saying? Do you have 5  instances of the same application, or 5 different applications? How do they get the log4j configuration?

Comment: @Andreas_D: I did not need more appenders. Each log4j.properties file will have its own appender.

Comment: @Kaj. I have 5 different applications. Each have its own log4j configuration. And how to get them is my question :)

Comment: Again - do you have 5 java application, each running in a different VM or do you have one VM hosting 5 (virtual) applications?

Comment: @Andreas_D: Actually these are 5 different projects on one VM.

Comment: @imran tariq - that's what I thought. The VM "has" *one* central logging service (your "log4j") that can't handle different log files. From a loggers point of view: everything inside a JVM is *one* application (unless you use different classloaders like application servers do)

Comment: @@Andreas_D: Thanks. Tell me how to use different classloaders to log messeages in my scenerio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log4j will automatically look for and use config files it finds on the classpath. It looks for files called `log4j.properties` and `log4j.xml` and possibly others.

Alternatively you can programatically load config using;

```
String filename = "/path/to/config/file.xml";
DOMConfigurator.configure(filename);
```